# Python SQlite: sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to select data from a sqlite database table. But keep on getting this error. I'm not sure if it is something to do with the comma in the limit() brackets.

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

Here is the affected code below.  I'm not sure if it is something to do with the comma in the limit() brackets. I've played around for hours with the code and have looked for solutions but can't find any.

```
selectMaleRow = cur.execute("SELECT * from " + sessionName + " where gender='M' limit([randowRow], 1)")
```

Comment: Complete guess: `cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM {} WHERE gender='M' LIMIT ?""".format(sessionName), (randRow[1],))` does that work? You haven't provided any real info in what you're trying to do.

Comment: @roganjosh I have got this error for that line TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What are you trying to do with `limit([randowRow], 1)`?

Comment: Another guess: `cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM {} WHERE gender='M' LIMIT ?""".format(sessionName), (max(randRow, 1),))`.

Comment: `limit([randowRow], 1)?` is going to select 1 random row.

Comment: You need to use `ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1`.